# Slight deformation of rear bumper

Tags: body

After a low-speed parking lot encounter with a brick wall, the rear bumper on my e36 m3 has about a 1" gap from the body panel right above it, on the right wheel-well.  It looks as if someone facing the right wheel grabbed the bumper and twisted it clockwise slightly. It's not rubbing on anything, and it doesn't look like it's about to come off, but it's a little unsightly.

Is there a trivially easy/cheap way to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lay down and look under the bumper. Compare the damaged side to the undamaged side. One or more of the clips or screws that hold the bumper in place may have been broken or bent.

If you can't see an obvious problem, then you can look up instructions in a repair manual for removing the bumper. Those will show you where all the attachment points are. Barring that, you'll have to take it to a body shop.